# Line 36: Mismatched input '+=' expecting ')'. Error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a basic strategy where it buys if the RSI increases by 5 and if the RSI is less than or equal to 50, and sells if the RSI decreases by 5 and is greater than or equal to 70. When I try to run this I get the error "Line 36: Mismatched input '+=' expecting ')'", which is the first 'if' statement. Below is my strategy. Any help would be appreciated.

```
timePeriod = time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2022, 6, 1, 0, 0)
notInTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0

//Stop Loss and Take Profit for Long
Stop_loss= ((input (1))/100)
Take_profit= ((input (4)/100))
longStopPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - Stop_loss)
longTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Take_profit)

//RSI
length = input(14)
price = close
vrsi = ta.rsi(price, length)

increase = 5
if ((vrsi += increase) and vrsi <= 50 and timePeriod and notInTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

decrease = 5
if ((vrsi -= decrease) and vrsi >= 70 and timePeriod)    
    strategy.exit(id='Exit', stop = longTakeProfit, limit = longStopPrice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to compare current rsi with previous rsi and see if it changed by more than increase/decrease values. Example below

```
//@version=5

strategy(title="RSI Inc  Dec Buy Sell", overlay = true)
timePeriod = time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2022, 6, 1, 0, 0)
notInTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0

//Stop Loss and Take Profit for Long
Stop_loss= ((input (1))/100)
Take_profit= ((input (4)/100))
longStopPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - Stop_loss)
longTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Take_profit)

//RSI
length = input(14)
price = close
vrsi = ta.rsi(price, length)

increase = 5
if ((vrsi > vrsi[1]+increase) and vrsi <= 50 and timePeriod and notInTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

decrease = 5
if ((vrsi < vrsi[1]+decrease) and vrsi >= 70 and timePeriod)    
    strategy.exit(id='Exit', stop = longTakeProfit, limit = longStopPrice)
```